# Switch between three radio buttons using keyboard shortcuts in vb.net project

Tags: vb.net, radiobuttonlist, windowsformsintegration

I have three radio buttons in my vb.net windows forms application project. Now I want to switch (or toggle) between these three buttons using keyboard shortcuts like Alt+S. Please help.

Comment: Get ready for a raid of comments asking you what have you tried and where's your error, cause that's a missing part in your question. This is not a freelancing forum we help you fix your code.

Comment: Instead of using a single key combination, use a different one for each by way of an accelerator key.  For instance, if you set the text of three `RadoButtons` to "&First", "&Second" and "&Third" then you can use Alt+F, Alt+T and Alt+S to select them.

Answer (score 0):

tested and works, next time please make a bit more effort with your research

on load:

```
Me.KeyPreview = True
```

on keydown:

```
If e.Alt AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.S Then
    if RB1.checked = true then
        RB2.checked = true
    elseif RB2.checked = true
        RB3.checked = true
    elseif RB3.checked = true
        RB1.checked = true
    end if
end if
```

Avoiding RBs check:

on load:

```
Me.KeyPreview = True
dim vall as integer = 1
```

on keydown:

```
If e.Alt AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.S Then
    select case vall
        case 1
            RB2.checked = true
            vall = 2
        case 2
            RB3.checked = true
            vall = 3
        case 3
            RB1.checked = true
            vall = 1
    end select
end if
```

Comment: No, this code will create a chain reaction which will come back to RB1 check status. I have tried it previously. I am looking for some solutions by using "select.....case" statement. Btw thanks for realising my problem so easily...

Comment: well if you want a select case you can always have an integer and when you do ctrl + S that integer changes and select case will be checking that integer and changing the RBs accordingly

Comment: Yup... Thanks a lot.